# Firefox Add-On, change preferences depending on connection

Tags: firefox, proxy, firefox-addon, tor

I would like to create my own Add-On that changes preferences depending on the proxy (if a proxy is being used or not), is that possible? I asked in a Firefox Add-On IRC but didn't a response, all users were idle.

Example:

```
// If proxy is enabled
lockPref("general.appname.override", "Netscape");
lockPref("general.appversion.override", "5.0 (Windows)");
lockPref("general.buildID.override", "20100101");
lockPref("general.oscpu.override", "Windows NT 6.1; Win32");
lockPref("general.platform.override", "Win32");
lockPref("general.productsub.override", "20100101");
lockPref("general.useragent.locale", "en-US");
lockPref("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0");
```

Comment: IRC is a bit slow just ogtta wait around. But yes this is very possible. I'm not sure of the code on how to detect proxy but it shouldnt be tough.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Noitidart, I would like some preferences to change when using Tor (127.0.0.1) but change back when I disable the proxy. I'm using Kali Linux and the tools I've seen are for Windows. Does having Linux limit me from being able to creating an Add-On?

Comment: Nope you're good man you have everything at your tips. I just dont have experience with proxy's and am busy with some stuff so I cant dig into this right now.

Comment: I've done a little digging but haven't found much info, I know there's many Add-Ons that change firefox preferences (example: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/privacy-settings), that's something I'd like to create but it being automatic when proxy a is enabled/disabled. I appreciate the fact that you're busy but still find the time to help me out :)

Comment: If you want to detect Tor automatically, you could try to open a connection to 127.0.0.1:9050 (default Tor socksport) and if you're able to connect then Tor's socks proxy may be running.